# Thread scheduler in C

Tags: algorithm, c, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, kernel

I have made a simple round robin scheduler that switches between threads in `ptable` array. Currently it's only for 1 CPU, so there are no locks at the moment.

But each CPU has its own `curproc` variable with the help of the GS register.

More details in the comments.

proc.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "franklin/switch.h"
#include "franklin/apic.h"
#include "franklin/mmu.h"
#include "franklin/proc.h"
#include "asm/x86.h"

#define NPROC 255

struct proc *curproc;
struct proc ptable[NPROC];


struct proc* set_current_proc(struct proc *p) {
  wrmsr((uint64_t)p);
  swapgs();
  return p;
}

struct proc* get_current_proc() {

  struct proc *p;

  swapgs();
  rdmsr(&p);
  if (p == 0) // if p = 0, it means swapgs() swapped the wrong way, so we need to swap again
    swapgs(); rdmsr(&p);
  
  return p;
}

void startproc(struct proc *p) {

  struct proc *current;
  
  curproc = get_current_proc();
  curproc->state = RUNNING;

  // this useless stack needs to be "saved" somewhere
  stack *discard;
  switc(&discard, p->stack);
}

void allocproc(uintptr_t *entry) {
  static uint32_t nextpid = 0;
  struct proc *p;
  
  p = &ptable[nextpid];
  p->pid = nextpid++;

  // palloc(1) allocates 1 page in phys memory and returns a physical addr
  p->stack = (stack*)P2V((uintptr_t)palloc(1));
  p->stack->rip = (uintptr_t)entry;
    
  p->state = RUNNABLE;
}


void scheduler() {

  struct proc *p, *prev;
  static uint8_t i = 1; // note: this is static

  // find next runnable process
  while ((p = &ptable[i++]) && p->state != RUNNABLE) {
    if (i == NPROC)
      i = 0;
  }
  
  prev = get_current_proc();
  curproc = set_current_proc(p);
  curproc->state = RUNNING;

  // save current stack on the previous process's struct
  // and switch to new process
  switc(&prev->stack, curproc->stack); 
}
```

x86.h

```
static void swapgs() {
  asm("swapgs":::"memory");
}

// "rdmsr" instruction returns the value in EDX:EAX
static void rdmsr(uint64_t **val) {
  uint64_t rdx, rax;
  asm volatile(
      "mov $0xc0000102, %%rcx;"
      "rdmsr;"
      : "=a"(rax), "=d"(rdx)
           );
  *val = rax | (uint64_t)rdx << 32;
}

// "wrmsr" instruction writes the 64 bit value in EDX:EAX
static void wrmsr(uint64_t val) {
  asm(
      "mov %0, %%edx;"
      "mov %1, %%eax;"
      "mov $0xc0000102, %%rcx;"
      "wrmsr;"
      ::
       "r"((uint32_t)(val >> 32)),
       "r"((uint32_t)val)
      : "rdx", "rax", "rcx"
      );
}
```

proc.h

```
#ifndef _PROC_
#define _PROC_


void scheduler(void);

enum procstate {
        UNUSED,
        RUNNABLE,
        RUNNING,
};


struct proc {
  regs_t *regs;
  stack *stack;
  enum procstate state;
  uint32_t pid;
};


#endif
```

isr.asm

```
    ; only push registers that belong to the called function,  
 the C function that gets called will save the rest of the registers
    %macro pushregs 0
    push rbp
    push rax
    push rcx
    push rdx
    push rdi
    push rsi
    push r8
    push r9
    push r10
    push r11
    %endmacro


    %macro popregs 0
    pop r11
    pop r10
    pop r9
    pop r8
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rax
    pop rbp
    %endmacro

    
    extern trap


    %macro isr_stub 1
isr_handler_%1: 
    push %1
    jmp alltraps
    %endmacro

global ret
alltraps:
    cld
    pushregs
    mov rbp, rsp
    and rsp, ~0xf    ; 16 byte align stack
    mov rdi, rbp     ; pass stack as parameter to trap function
    call trap
ret:    
    mov rsp, rbp        ; this works even after scheduling, because 'trap'
                ; will save the rbp on entry
    popregs
    add rsp, 8      ; irq number
    iretq
```

switch.asm

```
    global switc
switc:
    push rbp
    mov qword [rdi], rsp
    mov rsp, rsi
    pop rbp
    ret
```

and switch.h

```
typedef struct {
  uint64_t r11;
  uint64_t r10;
  uint64_t r9;
  uint64_t r8;
  uint64_t rsi;
  uint64_t rdi;
  uint64_t rdx;
  uint64_t rcx;
  uint64_t rax;
  uint64_t rbp;
  uint64_t code;
  /* uint64_t errcode; */
  uint64_t rip;
  uint64_t cs;
  uint64_t eflags;
} __attribute__((packed))regs_t;

typedef struct {
  unsigned long rbp;
  unsigned long rip;
} __attribute__((packed))stack;
```

apic.c

```
extern void scheduler(void);
extern struct proc *curproc;


void apic_timer(regs_t *regs) {
  *EOI = 0;

  curproc->state = RUNNABLE;
  scheduler();
}
```

trap.c

```
extern uint32_t* EOI;
void trap(regs_t *regs) {

// this function is not really implemented yet

  switch(regs->code) {
  case 32:
    timerh(10);
    break;
  case 33:
    kbd_press();
    break;
  case 34:
   apic_timer(regs);
    break;
  }


};
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what about this is [tag:algorithm].  It would make more sense to me to tag this [tag:assembly].  I would also find [tag:x86] more useful than [tag:kernel].  And this is a task scheduler, not [tag:scheduled-tasks].

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   if (p == 0) // if p = 0, it means swapgs() swapped the wrong way, so we need to swap again
>     swapgs(); rdmsr(&p);
> ```

This is a really weird way to write it.  It becomes a lot clearer if you write it with curly braces.

```
  // if p = 0, it means swapgs() swapped the wrong way, so we need to swap again
  if (0 == p) {
    swapgs();
  }

  rdmsr(&p);
```

Otherwise, perhaps someone might think that it was intended to be

```
  // if p = 0, it means swapgs() swapped the wrong way, so we need to swap again
  if (0 == p) {
    swapgs();
    rdmsr(&p);
  }
```

Note:  if you were under the impression that the quoted code worked like the last, then that is exactly why some of us recommend never using the statement form of control structures.  Because they don't work that way.

I am somewhat of the opinion that the last block is how it should be written.  Because I think that if you don't swap again, `rdmsr` is a no-op.  But perhaps I am misunderstanding.  I don't actually know x86 assembly.

Regardless, it is confusing to put a statement that will always execute on the same line as a statement that executes conditionally.  Even if it were important to save space, then

```
  if (0 == p) swapgs();
  rdmsr(&p);
```

is much clearer.  But there isn't really a reason to save space.

In my opinion, splitting the statement form across two lines doesn't help it.  It would be far superior to use the three or four lines of the block form (with curly braces).

Similarly, in C, it is often helpful to put constants on the left of the `==`, because `if (p = 0)` is valid C.  Valid in the sense that it will compile.  However, of course it won't ever run the conditional statement and it would overwrite `p`.  Meanwhile, `if (0 = p)` would give a compiler error.  So `if (0 == p)` is safer, because it is harder to mess it up in a way that won't be noticed immediately.  This can be controversial, because some don't like the way that it reads.

I find comments clearer if they are always written on their own lines.  And of course that prevents side scroll in the Stack format in this case.